# Highcharts: Uncommon x axis value set at the end of the graph.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

[image]

I have two series only one difference in both series that `2018-07-09` is not exist in first series thats why graph show that point at the end of the graph that is wrong.

```
My Series are:
series: [{name: "Grouped rep_oos",
  data: 
   [{name: "2018-07-01", y: 1.1},
    {name: "2018-07-02", y: 2.02},
    {name: "2018-07-03", y: 3.85},
    {name: "2018-07-04", y: 0.0},
    {name: "2018-07-05", y: 2.6},
    {name: "2018-07-06", y: 1.06},
    {name: "2018-07-07", y: 2.86},
    {name: "2018-07-08", y: 0.98},
    {name: "2018-07-10", y: 4.94},
    {name: "2018-07-11", y: 4.21},
    {name: "2018-07-12", y: 6.32},
    {name: "2018-07-13", y: 2.73},
    {name: "2018-07-14", y: 1.08},
    {name: "2018-07-15", y: 1.08},
    {name: "2018-07-16", y: 0.0},
    {name: "2018-07-17", y: 0.78},
    {name: "2018-07-18", y: 0.0},
    {name: "2018-07-19", y: 3.95},
    {name: "2018-07-20", y: 2.9},
    {name: "2018-07-21", y: 3.64}],
  yAxis: 1,
  type: "line"},
 {name: "Grouped change_in_conversion_prior_period",
  data: 
   [{name: "2018-07-01", y: 37.44},
    {name: "2018-07-02", y: -56.74},
    {name: "2018-07-03", y: 30.89},
    {name: "2018-07-04", y: 12.55},
    {name: "2018-07-05", y: 52.73},
    {name: "2018-07-06", y: -41.49},
    {name: "2018-07-07", y: 47.71},
    {name: "2018-07-08", y: 18.54},
    {name: "2018-07-09", y: 53.38},
    {name: "2018-07-10", y: -48.15},
    {name: "2018-07-11", y: -57.37},
    {name: "2018-07-12", y: 116.67},
    {name: "2018-07-13", y: -53.5},
    {name: "2018-07-14", y: 102.76},
    {name: "2018-07-15", y: 91.67},
    {name: "2018-07-16", y: -30.68},
    {name: "2018-07-17", y: -27.08},
    {name: "2018-07-18", y: 100.0},
    {name: "2018-07-19", y: -26.32},
    {name: "2018-07-20", y: 2.28},
    {name: "2018-07-21", y: 15.8}],
  yAxis: 1,
  type: "line"}]
```

Comment: you need to sort the data get a smooth chart...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 solutions :

**Changing xAxis.type and the date format** [API Doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    ...
    series: [{
        name: "Grouped rep_oos",
            data: [
                [1530403200000, 1.1],
                [1530489600000, 2.02],
                ...
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/5ukn214o/)

**Add null data for empty and connectNulls** [API Doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.connectNulls)

```
data:[
    ...
    {name: "2018-07-09", y:null},
    ...],
connectNulls: true,
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/2gcdL30s/)

Comment: Your first solution is not applying correctly and the second one is hard to implement in-fact its like  odd solution how can I find the missing point from my above series data

Comment: *Your first solution is not applying correctly* what is wrong ?

Comment: *how can I find the missing point from my above series data* I think you do a loop to retrieve your data so if there is no data for 1 day you can add the `null` value

Comment: I'm trying to apply your second solution, but please tell me how can i set `y: null` because ruby use `nil`

Comment: And When I change nil to null to changed to 0.0

Comment: Sorry I never used Ruby I can't help you there.

Answer (score 0):

The names of the categories are created from the first series and then they are supplemented from the others, so in your case you can simply change the order of the series.

```
series: [{
    name: "Grouped change_in_conversion_prior_period",
    data: [{
            name: "2018-07-01",
            y: 37.44
        },
        {
            name: "2018-07-02",
            y: -56.74
        },
        ...
    ],
    type: "line"
}, {
    name: "Grouped rep_oos",
    data: [{
            name: "2018-07-01",
            y: 1.1
        },
        {
            name: "2018-07-02",
            y: 2.02
        },
        ...
    ],
    type: "line"
}]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2d4Lmraj/

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs, because you're trying to pass the date as category name (`name: [string_value]`).

The way out of that is (as @Core972 said before) set your `xAxis.type` to `datetime`, but also process your data, because it should be passed as the timestamp value. You can achieve it by writing simple processing function, please take a look below:

```
function processData(data) {
  var processed = []

  data.forEach(function(series) {
    processed.push({
      name: series.name,
      data: series.data.map(data => {
        var myDate = data.name
        myDate = myDate.split("-").map(elem => { return parseInt(elem) });

        return [Date.UTC(myDate[0], myDate[1], myDate[2]), data.y]
      }),
      type: series.type
    })
  })

  return processed
}
```

Function above takes one argument, which is your series (with current structure ofc.), and returns the array with processed series objects.

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/h2rydgkc/